# Фильтр ответов с Google Forms через триггер onFormSubmit

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script, google-forms

У меня есть три колонки Google Sheet: Gender, Name, Email;
Когда пользователь отправляет форму, я хочу записывать все ответы с `gender == "Male"` в отдельный лист "Males" таблицы.
Вот мое нерабочее решение:

```
function onItemAdd(e) {
  var formData = e.values;
  if (formData[1] == "Male") {
    Logger.log(formData[1]);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]);
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Male").getDataRange().getValues()[0];
    var formRow = e.range;
    var filteredCell = formRow.getCell(1, formRow.getLastColumn()).offset(0, 1).setValue(formData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно искать введённые значения в форме, они уже есть в e.values. Просто вставить их в нужное место:

```
function onItemAdd(e) { 
  var formData = e.values;
  if (formData[1] == "Male") {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Male');
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, formData.length).setValues([formData]);
  }
}
```

Скрипт вставляет строку на всякий случай, чтобы лист не переполнился.

---

А вообще, нужен ли здесь скрипт? Можно просто поместить на листе "Male" формулу

```
=filter('Form Responses 1'!A:D, 'Form Responses 1'!B:B = "male")
```